# Apparent trill in the "br" of "bridge"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I occasionally hear "br" in words such as *bridge*, *bring* or *British*, pronounced with almost a bilabial trill.

One example is the word "bring" in The Assumption Song by OneyNG, around 35 seconds in.

Is it a dialect thing? Does it have a name? Am i imagining it? It certainly sounds nothing like the careful pronunciation samples in online dictionaries.

Thank you. I know nothing about linguistics, but hope you might have an answer. Any terms that I have used incorrectly are the result of my ignorance.

Comment: It's possibly being used instead of an alveolar trill (rolled R) by someone who can't roll their Rs properly in a dialect that uses rolled Rs. Non-standard, then, but there is a lot of variation in R sounds, including various non-standard pronunciations.

Comment: It would help to provide information on who is doing this, where they are from, what dialect they speak, etc. (I have never heard of OneyNG, and it's good to have this info in the question.)

Comment: Bilabial trills are a completely different thing from coronal trills or uvular trills. You meant coronal trill, not bilabial.

Comment: @tchrist That's what I initially thought, but then I realised that for those people who have a labiodental flap or labiodental approximate for an /r/, which is quite common now in so-called RP, there is often a small bilabial trill, I think, in words that begin with a bilabial plosive. I've never noticed that this is what it is, but I've used it as a quick diagnostic to tell if a speaker has a labiodental /r/, although it only works to rule it in. Its absence doesn't rule it out. It sounds very distinctive. So you might get it in words like *bring* or *princess*.

Comment: @StuartF, I don't have good examples. OneyNG is Irish. IIRC, Lindybeige and the members of Yogscast sometimes do it. I found three more clips. I don't associate it with Americans. You be the judge. First clip at 8:23 - 8:29 [both say "bright," second pronunciation is more distinct](https://youtu.be/AvrNUFoBl9U?t=503). Secondly, (exasperated) at 3:32 [the word "brilliant"](https://youtu.be/qr6jNsOeWtU?t=212). Finally, a possible instance at 0:48 - 0:53 (misspeaks) ["BRAGE"](https://youtu.be/1BtEfUOyLxc?t=48).

Comment: I think in the case of the song by OneyNG it is just done to slightly stretch the word to fit the rhythm. In normal speech maybe some Scots dialects?

Comment: Further to Stuart F's Comment above, to what is 'almost a bilabial trill' opposed, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, oh. "Almost" was a meek attempt to hide my ignorance of linguistics. In my efforts to imitate native accents, I learned this quirk by tightening my lips and "over-blowing" the start of a word. With a quick search, the closest thing I found was a "bilabial trill;" however, Wikipedia claimed those don't exist in English.

My best guess is that I just chanced upon a few people with a strange accent while learning English.

Comment: Thanks and I hope I'n not the only one to wish you'd started by saying that!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I apologise for being unclear. Feel free to edit the question to better fit this community. Given that there likely isn't an interesting answer (past what was stated in the comments), maybe the question should be closed.

Comment: Thanks and I do not feel qualified to do that. However, your detailed knowledge of the Question and understanding of all the Comments should qualify you, yourself…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Araucaria's comment pointed me in the right direction, specifically this line:

> for those people who have a labiodental flap or labiodental approximate for an /r/, which is quite common now in so-called RP, there is often a small bilabial trill, I think, in words that begin with a bilabial plosive

In some dialects (particularly of British English), R can be pronounced as a labiodential approximant [ʋ] ([see Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_/r/#R-labialization)), a process known as *R-labialization.* As [Scobbie (2006) notes](https://eresearch.qmu.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/20.500.12289/2177/scobbie_%2528r%2529_2006_ELL2_00004711.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y):

> With heavily labialized /r/, bilabial trills corresponding to the clusters /br/ and /pr/ can even be found.

Unfortunately, Scobbie does not cite any sources for this claim, so all I can say is that you and Araucaria are not the first to notice this phenomenon.

Answer (score -1):

The "bbr" sound in the Assumption Song is closer to an emphasis on the "br" in the word "bring" than a trill.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).